# How can I get windows explorer to "browse to next folder"? (vbscript/batch etc...)

Tags: image, windows-xp, directory, autohotkey

I use the basic windows explorer to browse a large collection of images. I have a very well organised group of folders and I don't need/want any of the extra functionality of photo organisers such as picasa etc...

The only drawback is: I'd really like to be able to browse from one folder straight into the next, without having to click back and choosing the next folder.

So my question is, how could I do this in the smoothest way?!

I'm guessing I could use a combination of some script and then use auto hotkey to bind it to a key shortcut.

Any help/ideas/pointers very appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for now I'm using autohotkey and a little script.

It's not perfect as explorer has to jump up a folder and then down again but it works for now.

```
if WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") or WinActive("ahk_class" . ExplorerWClass)
 ^Up::
 SendEvent {Alt Down}{Left}{Alt Up}
 SendEvent {Up}
 Sleep 300
 SendEvent {Return}

 ^Down::
 SendEvent {Alt Down}{Left}{Alt Up}
 SendEvent {Down}
 Sleep 300
 SendEvent {Return}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need programming at all for this. I'm assuming you browse your images with the Windows Image Viewer.
To browse images sequentially in an entire folder tree, follow these steps:
1) Open the tree's root folder in Windows explorer
2) Click on the magnifying glass toolbar button
3) Click on the "search" button in the left panel
At this point you will have a full list of all files and folders in all folders and subfolders under the root folder you opened.
4) Now just click on one of the images to open it with the Windows Image Viewer
To go to the next/previous image in the folder tree just click on the next/previous image button at the bottom of the window.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion getfree, it's a useful tip but it doesnt quite work for me in this case. I have too many images and too weak a computer; the search takes ages and slows everything down. Also I have documents related to the pictures in the folders that I need access to.