# How to extend windows explorer functionality?

Tags: plugins, windows-xp, explorer

How would I go about extending the functionality of windows explorer in XP?

Is there some way whereby I could create a "plugin" of some sorts that could hook into explore.exe to add additional folder browsing functionality? What language could I use to achieve this?

This is an expansion of a question I asked [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575639/how-can-i-get-windows-explorer-to-browse-to-next-folder-vbscript-batch-etc)

Answer (score 3):

There's a great series of tutorials on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguideindex.aspx) which might help you. C++ is required there.

Comment: While the link above does load, many of the examples on the navigated page do not :(

Answer (score 0):

There is an old O'reilly book called ['Visual Basic Shell Programming'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565926706) that explains the API's for this in some detail.  While taken from a VB6-centric point of view, the API's are all exposed through COM, so they can be used from any language that supports this.  [This article](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ShellExtensions) discusses using the windows shell with .Net and a tool to build an interop assembly.