# Creating a Plugin for Windows File Explorer that runs when the user moves a file

Tags: c#, windows, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

I need to add a plugin to Windows Explorer that has very little functionality. Basically I want it to pop up a MessageBox when the user tries to move a file via Drag and Drop. I have looked for applications that have this functionality, but I have found nothing. I have also looked for the source code of plugins so that I could possibly understand how to do this and I still came up empty handed.

So, if anyone has any information on how I could build a plugin for Windows Explorer, please share your knowledge. Also, if you have any examples of this I would appreciate it.

I have never created a plugin so I am kind of clueless. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: You haven't mentioned the windows version for which you are developing . I guess its called windows shell extension. Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776778(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728901/how-to-extend-windows-explorer-functionality) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/529515/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Drop-Handlers)

Comment: Why do you need to display a message? Can you accomplish this by setting ACLs on the folder? A copy hook cannot be written in C#.

Comment: I am using Windows XP and Windows 7. I am wanting to display a message so that the user does not accidentally move a file into another folder.

Comment: You really don't want to do this. A shell extension is a heavyweight tool. It will run in the shell's most important process. If you make a mistake you will crash the shell. If you do this, make sure you ship a really good uninstall program!

Comment: Dang... What about just disabling the drag-and-drop feature in Windows Explorer? And ONLY in Windows Explorer haha.